# discord.py: How to do a leaderboard based on a coin system?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make a leaderboard based on a coin system.
I tried it with this: `sorted(lbcashusers, key=lambda x: lbcashusers[x].get('Total', 0), reverse=True)`
But it doesn't work and I'm stucked. I want the leaderboard listed in an embed message by `Total`.

My code now:

```
@bot.command(aliases=['lb', 'top'])
async def leaderboard(ctx, choice = None):
    if choice == '-cash':
        with open('casinomoney.json', 'r') as flbcash:
            lbcashusers = json.load(flbcash)

        lbcash = sorted(lbcashusers, key=lambda x: lbcashusers[x].get('Cash', 0), reverse=True)
        message = ''
        for number, user in enumerate(lbcash):
            message += '{0}. {1} with {2}Cash\n'.format(number + 1, user, lbcash[user].get('Cash', 0))
            await ctx.send(message)
```

My Json File:

```
{
    "146293573422284800": {
        "Bank": 1000,
        "Cash": 1,
        "Total": 1001
    },
    "155149108183695360": {
        "Bank": 2000,
        "Cash": 1,
        "Total": 2001
    },
    "270904126974590976": {
        "Bank": 3000,
        "Cash": 1,
        "Total": 3001
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you have already tried and "didn't work". It would help others a lot with pointing out what might have gone wrong.

Comment: okay, I edited now.